# spplot: put labels on the map

Tags: r, spatial

I seek help on how to change font size and font color for `sp.text` labels on the attached map—to avoid overlapping of labels and to improve readability.

Map was produced as below. If needed, one may download the `SpatialPolygonsDataframe` object 'mymap' [here](http://1drv.ms/1zRooEV).

`trellis.par.set()` is not solving my problem. Am I using it incorrectly?

```r
    library(sp)
    library(latticeExtra)

    # Create list object for sp.layout (Got these functions here on stackoverflow, thank you owner)
    sp.label <- function(x, label) {list("sp.text", coordinates(x), label)}
    NUMB.sp.label <- function(x) {sp.label(x, as.vector(x@data$NUMB))}
    make.NUMB.sp.label <- function(x) {do.call("list", NUMB.sp.label(x))}


    # Spplot
    tps <- list(fontsize=list(text=5), fontcolor=list(text="green"))
    trellis.par.set(tps)

    spplot(mymap, "indic", 
                    col.regions=c("#D3D3D3","#A9A9A9"),
                    sp.layout = make.NUMB.sp.label(mymap), 
                    cex = 0.5,
                    bg = "white", col="light grey", border="light grey")
```

[image]

Comment: The link to the 'mymap' object is broken, so there's no way to reproduce the output. It would be nice if you could do something about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution: Needed to add cex, col arguments in the list:

```
 list("sp.text", coordinates(x), label, cex=0.5, col="green")
```